# Exchange 2010 disabled account....will email redirect work?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

If user mailbox account has been disabled in exchange 2010, will email redirect still work? Or will the mailbox need to be enabled for the redirect to work?

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific about what you mean by "email redirect"

Comment: There are a couple of ways to set up email redirection in Exchange, which method are you referring to here?

Comment: Do you mean that the associated AD account is disabled?  If so, yes, email flow will still work.